# ListView, storage 2 columns [android]

Tags: android, listview

I need an advice about ListView.
A give you an example:

Assume that i have a map. If i'll touch some place on it i'll get an information about that place and then, on screen, a dialog fragment will appear. In this dialog i can write a name of place, which i touched. The names should be saved into ListView but if i'll click on some of them i want to get information.

Can some of you tell me how i should do this? Is it possible to save that information in Shared Preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would get it work with SharedPref. but it isn't a nice way to that. I think the best way is to create an [Android SQL-DataBase](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). Like in every other Database you could use one column for the name, one for the information text, one for coordinates and so on (that's just an example). The data will stay, also if your app is closed (like SharedPref).